# How to get created dates for files in a directory?

Tags: python, loops, file, date

I am stuck on this.  Not sure exactly what is going wrong.  When I run the below script, it comes out great but the creation date of the file, and the file size is all the same and should be.  Can one direct me where I am going wrong at?  I have to put this in a text file that shows the file names, date created, and file size plus filter the size.

```
import os
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

def get_file_size(path):
    size_info = os.stat(path)
    size = size_info.st_size
    return size


path = '/users/sarah/documents'


files = os.listdir(path)
created_time = os.stat(path).st_ctime
size = get_file_size(path)


for file in files:
    print("File Name:",file, "Created Date:",created_time, "File Size:", size,"bytes")
```

Comment: Your creation date and size are set outside of the loop and are set only once.  Hence, no change inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks the **folder's** creation date and size and then outputs them. If I understood correctly, you want to do this **for every file** separately.

Try this:

```
import os
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

def get_file_size(path):
    size_info = os.stat(path)
    size = size_info.st_size
    return size


path = '/users/sarah/documents'


files = os.listdir(path)
    
for file in files:
   created_time = os.stat(file).st_ctime
   size = get_file_size(file)
   print("File Name:",file, "Created Date:",created_time, "File Size:", size,"bytes")
```

It is basically the same code, with the `created_time` and `size` variables computed for every file individually.